# In MacOSX, can't get applescript+automator service working to send text from any application to "Sublime Text 3"

Tags: applescript, sublimetext3

Want to send text from any application to "Sublime Text 3" and this is how I am thinking of doing it

- Create an "automator" service
- Set a shortcut for it
- Call shortcut from app

I am able to create the "automator" service and it works fine when tested from within "automator" (by means of the "Get Text" action)

But, when I trigger shortcut from application, "Sublime Text" **does not open new tab** with the selected text (and does nothing)

This is how I am setting up the "automator" service

1. Service receives selected text in any application
2. Copy to Clipboard
3. Run this applescript

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       tell application "System Events"
           set frontmost of process "Sublime Text" to true
           tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
           tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
       end tell

   end run
   ```

Appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Sublime Text" to activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using command down
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end run
```

Note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may or may not need to be adjusted for timing on your system.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you :)

So, the issue was that the keystrokes were too fast together which was causing some kind of race condition?

Comment: @shriramks, There were several issues and if you compare my coding to yours, you'll see the differences. Yes, one of them can be timing and hence adding the `delay` _commands_. Also `set frontmost of process "Sublime Text" to true` didn't bring the Sublime Text window frontmost for me and why I used `tell application "Sublime Text" to activate`. You also do not need to use `tell application "System Events" to keystroke ...` within a `tell application "System Events"` _block_, simply use `keystroke ...` inside the _block_.